# Python: Help in optimizing code

Tags: python, optimization

I have a piece of code that is used to  calculate the cell centers in a rectangular mesh. The mesh size is pretty large (650 columns by 1150 rows). The code runs very slow. I was wondering if I could employ any tricks to reduce the runtime.In the example below, deltax is a 1D array of column spacings and deltay is a 1d array of row spacings.

```
center_x = np.empty((nrow,ncol),dtype ='double')
center_y = np.empty((nrow,ncol),dtype ='double')
for i in range(nrow-1,-1,-1):
    if(i == nrow-1):
        center_y[i,:] = 0.5*deltay[nrow-1]
    else:
        center_y[i,:] = center_y[i+1,:] + 0.5*deltay[i+1] + 0.5*deltay[i]

for j in range(0,ncol):
    if(j ==0):
        center_x[:,j] = 0.5*deltax[0]
    else:
        center_x[:,j]= center_x[0,j-1] + 0.5*deltax[j-1] + 0.5*deltax[j]
```

Comment: [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) is better suited for this type of question

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thank you. I will post this question on the appropriate forum.

Comment: Looks like each each statement goes to the `else` part for all but one iteration. In that case you don't need to branch, just take that part out of the loop

Comment: @jonrsharpe: that doesn't make it off-topic here; it may be *better* suited there but that's not a reason to close it.

Comment: I think you can also separately add deltay[i+1] and deltay[i] to center_y[i,:] (and same for the x's). If they are all numpy arrays, that might give you another slight boost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least two things:

```
for i in range(nrow-1,-1,-1):
    if(i == nrow-1):
        center_y[i,:] = 0.5*deltay[nrow-1]
    else:
        center_y[i,:] = center_y[i+1,:] + 0.5*deltay[i+1] + 0.5*deltay[i]
```

Can be changed to avoid branching:

```
center_y[nrow-1,:] = 0.5*deltay[nrow-1]
for i in range(nrow-2,-1,-1):
    center_y[i,:] = center_y[i+1,:] + 0.5*deltay[i+1] + 0.5*deltay[i]
```

And this leverages numpy a little more:

```
center_y[nrow-1,:] = 0.5*deltay[nrow-1]
center_y[:nrow-1, :] = 0.5*deltay[1:] + 0.5*deltay[:nrow-1]
# expl: deltay[i+1] in the loop skips the first element, deltay[i] skips the last element
for i in range(nrow-2,-1,-1): # can't move this part since center_y[i,:] depends on center_y[i+1,:] 
    center_y[i,:] = center_y[i+1,:]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
center_x[:,j]= center_x[0,j-1] + 0.5*deltax[j-1] + 0.5*deltax[j]
...
center_y[i,:] = center_y[i+1,:] + 0.5*deltay[i+1] + 0.5*deltay[i]
```

Do you have to assign to `[:,j]` and `[i,:]` and not just `[i]` and `[j]`? That's something like (but not exactly because there are multiple dimensions) bumping it up to O(n^2).

Comment: I do. I posted the code for a simple case where the mesh is not rotated. When the mesh is rotated, the cell centers change are different for the same column in different rows.